# How to check that h2 embedded database is created?

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc

I have *app-context* file with embedded database:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd">

    <jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="H2">
        <jdbc:script location="classpath:META-INF/schema.sql" />
        <jdbc:script location="classpath:META-INF/data.sql" />
    </jdbc:embedded-database>

    <bean id="reportDao" 
          class="jdbc.dao.ImplReportDao"
          p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" />

</beans>
```

And I have the following *src/META-INF/schema.sql* file:

```
USE `reports`;

/*Table structure for table `reports` */

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `reports`;

CREATE TABLE `reports` (
  `id` int(9) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL,
  `parent_id` int(9) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000',
  `name` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
  `is_category` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251;
```

and *src/META-INF/data.sql* file:

```
insert  into `reports`.`reports`(`id`,`parent_id`,`name`,`is_category`) 
values 
(0000,0000,'Reports',1),
(0001,0000,'Card emission',1),
(0002,0000,'Technical reports',1);
```

And `ImplReportDao` looks like this:

```
public class ImplReportDao implements ReportDao {
    private DataSource dataSource;

    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Report> findAll() {
        System.out.println("find all");
        List<Report> result = new ArrayList<Report>();
        Connection conn = null;     
        try {
            if (dataSource != null) {
                System.out.println("dataSource != null");
            } else {
                System.out.println("dataSource == null");
            }

            conn = dataSource.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement("select * from reports");
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                Report report = new Report();
                report.setId(resultSet.getInt("id"));
                report.setParentId(resultSet.getInt("parent_id"));
                report.setName(resultSet.getString("name"));
                result.add(report);
            }
            return result;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

And *Main* class looks like:

```
public class Main {
    private static ReportDao reportDao = new ImplReportDao();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Report> reports = reportDao.findAll();
        for (Report report : reports) {
            System.out.println("report: " + report.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

But after launch I've got the error `NullPointerException` because in `ImplReportDao.findAll()` `dataSource` is null. How can I check whether h2 embedded database is created?

Comment: Hi, you can open up H2 console in your browser and see if the database and table exist.

Comment: But I didn't deploy my app in Tomcat, I'm trying to run it in Eclipse using Gradle. Is it possible to do it right in Eclipse, or I must to deploy the app in Tomcat first?

Comment: You can use application.properties in the resource folder and specify h2console path. After that, when you'll launch your app, you can access h2 console over localhost:8080/__your_path_here___ (h2cosole by default)

Comment: `spring.h2.console.enabled=true //Enable the console.` 
`spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console //Path at which the console will be available.` here is the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You configure your databae in Spring but then create object using constructor. You do not create Spring context that is why database is not created. Also because you use constructor Spring cannot inject datasource into your newly created object because Spring IoC container doesn't know about it.

So you need to make several changes in your code and config XML.

First, to use `p:dataSource-ref` you need to add this line into heade of your XML file: `xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"` right after `xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"`.

Second you need to instantiate Spring context like this

```
public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("app-context.xml"); //assuming app-context.xml is in classpath of project
    ReportDao reportDao = ctx.getBean(ReportDao.class); //Ask Spring to gice you DAO object with injected dataSource
    List<Report> reports = reportDao.findAll();
    for (Report report : reports) {
        System.out.println("report: " + report.getName());
    }
  }
}
```